# Python Pandas Conditions

Tags: pandas

If make of car is "Peugeot" and Model is "2008" i want write Make = PEUGEOT

if Make of car is "Peugeot" and Model isn't "2008" i want write Make = Peugeot

is it possible to do and if possible how?

**df.loc[df[Make].str.contains('PEUGEOT', case=False) & df[Model].str.contains('2008', case=False), Make] = 'PEUGEOT'**

**df.loc[df[Make].str.contains('PEUGEOT', case=False) & ~df[Model].str.contains('2008', case=False), Make] = 'Peugeot'**

BUt i have error : bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'

Answer (score 0):

place the condition in parenthesis. if you post the data, it help to reproduce and share the result

```
df.loc[df[Make].str.contains('PEUGEOT', case=False) & (  ~df[Model].str.contains('2008', case=False) )  , Make] = 'Peugeot'
```